# Generic Exponential Backoff Retry Mechanism C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

I have written a generic exponential backoff retry loop in C++11. I'm using `std::function` to pass the callable to retry loop. `callable` will be retried if `isRetriable` function returns true.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

constexpr int64_t max_backoff_milliseconds = 30000; // 30 seconds

template <class R, class... Args>
R Retry(int max_retry_count, int64_t initial_dealy_milliseconds,
    const std::function<bool(R)> &isRetriable,
    const std::function<R(Args...)> &callable, Args &&... args)
{
    int retry_count = 0;
    while (true) {
        auto status = callable(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        if (!IsRetriable(status)) {
            return status;
        }

       if (retry_count >= max_retry_count) {
           // Return status and abort retry
           return status;
       }
       int64_t delay_milliseconds = 0;
       if (initial_dealy_milliseconds > 0) {
           delay_milliseconds =
               std::min(initial_dealy_milliseconds << retry_count,
                     max_backoff_milliseconds);
       }
       std::cout << "Callable execution failed. Retry Count:"
              << retry_count + 1 << std::endl;
       std::this_thread::sleep_for(
           std::chrono::milliseconds(delay_milliseconds));
      retry_count++;
   }
}

bool isRetriable(int status) {
    if (status == 5)
       return true;
    return false;
}

int foo(int x, int y) {
    static int a = 1;
    a += (x + y);
    return a / 6;
}

int main() {
    auto result = Retry(1000, 100, isRetriable, foo, 1, 3);
    std::cout << result << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile it, I'm getting below error:

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:50:71: error: no matching function for call to ‘Retry(int, 
int, bool (&)(int), int (&)(int, int), int, int)’
auto result = Retry<int, int, int>(1000, 100, isRetriable, foo, 1, 3);
                                                                   ^
prog.cpp:11:3: note: candidate: template<class R, class ... Args> R 
Retry(int, int64_t, const std::function<bool(R)>&, const 
std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>&, Args&& ...)
R Retry(int max_retry_count,
^~~~~
prog.cpp:11:3: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
prog.cpp:50:71: note:   mismatched types ‘const 
std::function<int(_ArgTypes ...)>’ and ‘int(int, int)’
auto result = Retry<int, int, int>(1000, 100, isRetriable, foo, 1, 3);
                                                                   ^
```

Could someone explain to me why I have this error?

Comment: You are (trying to) call a function with a different signature than exists.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there's a good duplicate for this but...

Here's a shorter reproduction:

```
template <typename T> void foo(std::function<bool(T)> ) { }
bool maybe(int ) { return false; }

foo(maybe); // error: no matching function call to 'foo(bool (&)(int))'
```

You may ask - what?! `maybe` *is* something that's callable with some `T` that returns `bool`. But that's not how template deduction works. In order to deduce `std::function<bool(T)>` against an argument, that argument *needs to be a* `std::function`. `maybe` isn't a `std::function`, it's just a function, so that deduction fails. Any kind of deduction with a different kind of expression will also fail:

```
foo([](int ) { return true; }); // also error
```

Basically, trying to *deduce* a `std::function` is almost always the wrong thing to do. First, it's wrong because it won't work. Second, it's wrong because even if it did work, you're incurring type erasure in a context in which you probably don't need it.

What you want to do instead is deduce arbitrary callables, and then determine what these other arguments are based on those callables. The return type of `callable` is just what you get when you call `callable` with `Args...`, and you want to ensure that `isRetriable` is a predicate on that type.

One approach to that is:

```
template <typename Predicate, typename Callable, typename... Args,
    // figure out what the callable returns
    typename R = std::decay_t<std::invoke_result_t<Callable&, Args...>>,
    // require that Predicate is actually a Predicate
    std::enable_if_t<
        std::is_convertible_v<std::invoke_result_t<Predicate&, R>, bool>,
        int> = 0>
R Retry(int max_retry_count, int64_t initial_dealy_milliseconds,
    Predicate&& isRetriable,
    Callable&& callable,
    Args&&... args)
{
    // ....
}
```

Comment: and in C++14 drop all of the enable_if and invoke_result stuff and just return `auto` for 90% of the functionality for 10% of the work.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont - Can you help with the C++14 solution for the retry mechanism shown in the question. Want to know the signature of the function and how it will be called.